# Complex Frequency Shifting in Fourier Transform

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, residue-calculus, fourier-transform

When dealing with Fourier transforms, it is often useful to take advantage of the following property in order to simplify work: 
$$\mathcal{F}(e^{i\omega_0t}f(t))=G(\omega-\omega_0)$$

where $G(\omega)=\mathcal{F}(f(t))$, and $\omega_0 \in \mathbb{R}$. Is there a more general relation where $\omega_0 \in \mathbb{C}$? I know that, physically speaking, having a complex frequency shift (or complex time shift) does not have a meaning, but mathematically it could transform a sinusoidal function, for example, into a hyperbolic one. In short, is there a quick mathematical trick to doing a complex shift? If so, what is it? If not, why?

***My guess*** is that a complex shift would cause the residues to move around  the plane relatively to the real line, either keeping them on the same side, or moving them across. This would require a case by case study to determine the result. So there might not be a general relation of the form shown above. *And come to think of it, it might be related to the stability of the system the function might model.*

Any input is appreciated...

Comment: If $\omega_0 \in \mathbb C$ then we can write $\omega_0 = a_0 + ib_0$ where $a_0, b_0 \in \mathbb R$. Then $e^{i\omega_0 t}f(t) = e^{a_0 t} e^{ib_0 t}f(t)$, but this is not  generally integrable on $\mathbb R$ if $a_0 \neq 0$ (not without constraints on $f$, anyway). So you should clarify what is meant by Fourier transform in this case.

Comment: Assuming $f$ is constrained so that the integral makes sense, you are essentially describing the [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform)

Comment: @Bungo Clarify in what way? Do you mean it should be redefined in order to handle complex frequencies? And yes, I have thought of it becoming the Laplace Transform, but this makes things more complicated as the function now includes the exponential, and the boundaries of the integral are different.

Comment: Well, if $\omega_0$ is real, then  $\mathcal F(e^{i \omega_0 t} f(t))$ makes sense for any function $f$ that has a Fourier transform, because $|e^{i \omega_0 t}| = 1$. But if $\omega_0$ is not real, then $e^{i \omega_0 t}$ factors into two components $e^{at}$ and $e^{i bt}$. The latter is no problem as it has absolute value $1$, but the former grows exponentially in either the positive $t$ or negative $t$ direction, depending on the sign of $a$. So unless $f$ decays at least as fast (or, e.g. is compactly supported), the integral defining the Fourier transform does not converge.

Comment: @Bungo This further explains Hans' answer. If you can post this comment as an answer I would gladly accept it!

Comment: Laplace. Ah Bungo was faster. And you need to take care that exponent-shift which now will be real does not exceed 0 so it grows without bounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer by **Hans** is good and explains under what conditions this makes sense. The OP asked me to post my comment as an answer. To justify this, I'll try to expand it with a bit more detail.

There are various conventions for defining the Fourier transform. I will assume we are working with the following:
$$\hat{f}(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t) e^{-i \omega t} dt$$
Then, applying the definition to the function $g(t) = e^{i \omega_0 t}f(t)$, we can manipulate **formally** as follows:
$$\begin{aligned}
\hat{g}(\omega) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{i\omega_0 t}e^{-i \omega t} dt \\
& = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t) e^{-i(\omega - \omega_0)t} dt \\
&= \hat{f}(\omega - \omega_0)
\end{aligned}$$
Now, under what conditions does that above **formal** manipulation make sense?

Note that the integral defining the Fourier transform, namely
$$\hat{f}(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-i \omega t} dt$$
converges whenever $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(t)| dt$ conveges, in other words, whenever $f$ is absolutely integrable.

Now, if $\omega_0$ is real, then $|e^{i\omega_0 t}| = 1$, so
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{i \omega_0 t}e^{-i \omega t} dt$$
also converges whenever $f$ is absolutely integrable.

However, if $\omega_0$ is not real, then we can write $\omega_0 = a_0 + i b_0$, where $a_0$ and $b_0$ are both real, and $a_0$ is nonzero. Then $e^{i\omega_0 t} = e^{(a_0 + ib_0)t} = e^{a_0 t} e^{ib_0 t}$, so
$$|e^{i\omega_0 t}| = |e^{a_0 t}||e^{i b_0 t}| = |e^{a_0 t}| = e^{a_0 t}$$
Therefore, convergence of the integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{i \omega_0 t}e^{-i \omega t} dt$$
requires convergence of
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(t)|e^{a_0 t} dt$$
Now, $e^{a_0 t}$ grows exponentially in either the positive $t$ or negative $t$ direction, depending on the sign of $a_0$. Consequently, if the integral is to converge, we require $f$ to decay exponentially in that direction in order to compensate.

The conclusion is that when $\omega_0$ is real, the integral defining $\mathcal F(f(t) e^{i\omega t})$ always makes sense for any absolutely integrable function $f$. But when $\omega_0$ is not real, this is no longer the case. So one has to be careful about what conditions on $f$ and/or the real part of $\omega_0$ are required so that the integral will converge. The answer by **Hans** summarizes these conditions nicely.

Answer (score 3):

This is valid, so long as $|f(t)|=O(e^{b_-t})$ as $t\to\infty$ and $|f(t)|=O(e^{b_+t})$ as $t\to-\infty$ with $b_-<b_+$. Then $f(t)e^{bt}\in L^1(-\infty,\infty), \forall b\in(b_-,b_+)$ and the complex Fourier transform converges. Under this condition, the Fourier transform is analytic in $\omega=a+ib,\, a,b\in\mathbb R$ if $f(t)$ has finite number of finite discontinuity and finite number of extrema in any finite length interval, and this complex frequency shift is valid for a horizontal strip $\{a+ib\big| a,b\in\mathbb R,\,b\in (b_-,b_+)\}$ in the complex plane.