# Fourier Transform of a Gaussian Function in the Complex Domain - is it trivial?

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I want to calculate $$f(q)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty G(r)p(r)e^{iqr} dr$$ with complex $q$.

I know the Fourier transform of $p(r)$ for complex $q$. I.e. $f_{p}(q)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty p(r)e^{iqr} dr$ is solved.

and G(r) is a Gaussian function $$G(r)=e^{-ar^2}$$
I want to use the convolution theorem to solve this problem and thus need the Fourier transform of $G(r)$.
I know that for real $q$, the Fourier transform of a Gaussian is another Gaussian. My central question is: **is this still valid if $q$ is complex?**

Wikipedia seems to hint that the answer may not be trivial:
https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Fourier_transform#/Complex_domain

> "Depending on the properties of f, this might not converge off the
>   real axis at all, or it might converge to a complex analytic function
>   for all values of ξ = σ + iτ, or something in between"

and the explanation following that quote goes over my head. Despite searching I have yet to confirm this key detail.

So, please help me!: Is it true that the Fourier transform of a Gaussian function is still
 $$f_{g}(q)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ar^2} e^{iqr} dr = \sqrt{\pi/a} e^{-\pi^2 q^2 /a}$$ for complex $q$?
Thank you

Comment: Hint: try plugging in $q=-iax^2$. Does this converge?

Comment: Okay, so there's a singularity when $q=-iar$? (my mistake there with the notation by the way, not yours. I've updated it to remove the stray $x$). Am I going to need to get out my complex analysis notes from 10 years ago and try to find out if it's removable?

Comment: Note that $q$ is a constant, but $r$ variable being integrated against.

Comment: I'm still not sure I'm getting it!

Comment: I think this post answers the question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1864480/complex-frequency-shifting-in-fourier-transform

Comment: I have just posted my answer, which I think works. I get the impression you had something simpler in mind though, so please go ahead and correct me if I am unnecessarily over-complicating it! Or if you don't have the time, then thank you for your attempts to push me in the right direction.

Comment: I expected a suitable choice of q would make the integral not converge, likely due to thinking that you can set q with some r dependence for some reason. This doesn't turn out to be the case though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I think I figured this out with the help of this post:

[Complex Frequency Shifting in Fourier Transform](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1864480/complex-frequency-shifting-in-fourier-transform)

I want to confirm that

$$f_{g}(q)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ar^2} e^{iqr} dr = \sqrt{\pi/a} e^{-\pi^2 q^2 /a}$$

or otherwise find a similar solution, when $q$ is complex.

if $q=x+iy$ 
$$f_{g}(q)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ar^2} e^{i(x+iy)r} dr$$
or
$$f_{g}(q)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ar^2} e^{-yr} e^{ixr}  dr$$

Using the convolution theorem, this is equivalent to
$$f_{g}(q)=(\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ar^2} e^{ixr}  dr) \circledast (\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-yr} e^{ixr}  dr)$$
Which since the LHS is a Gaussian and the RHS is a plane wave is
$$f_{g}(q)=((\sqrt{\pi/a} e^{-\pi^2 x^2 /a}) \circledast(c \delta(x-y)))(x)$$
where c is some constant that may or may not exist, and which I am currently too tired to properly think about.

Then because the delta function is kind of like the identity function of convolution (something I vaguely remember from DSP - apologies if that is not rigourously true...), the convolution just scales the Gaussian by $c$ and shifts it by $y$... so the answer is
$$f_{g}(q)=c(\sqrt{\pi/a}) e^{-\pi^2 (x-y)^2 /a}$$
So the effect of complex q is just to scale and shift the resulting Gaussian.
I'm not 100% confident, and I suspect there's a simpler answer. I'd appreciate anyone jumping in to correct me if so!